# What does "{}" mean? When is a map empty?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

If I do

```
System.out.println(nameOfaHashMap);
```

when that map is "empty", the system says "`{}`".

In this case, is that map empty or null?

How can I write if I would:

```
if (nameOfanHashMap is != null)
{
    System.out.println(nameOfaHashMap);  
}
else System.out.println("I'm sorry, this map is empty!");
```

---

Thanks so much to everyone and sorry for my English e for my Java :-)
You reply me so fast, also thanks really to everyone.

I wrote this code, that is ok:

```
if (disponibilita.isEmpty())
{
   System.out.println("Sorry, ..");
}
else 
   System.out.println(disponibilita);
```

Comment: Why are you using `null` to represent an empty map?  It's almost always a *terrible* idea.  And even ignoring that, what's wrong with the code you propose below?, other than the word "is" ?

Comment: Why do you need the distinction between a `null` variable and it pointing to an empty map?

Comment: If you want to check if your map is empty, the map interface provide an `isEmpty()` method.

Answer (score 5):

If it's `null`, then it isn't even a map; if it's a map, only then it gets the chance of being empty.

An empty map's `toString` will commonly return `{}`, whereas `String.valueOf(null)` returns the string `"null"`, and this is what is printed.

If you want to print "sorry, this map is empty" when you have a map, but it is empty, then you need

```
if (map.isEmpty()) System.out.println("sorry, this map is empty");
```

Answer (score 2):

As said in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html#toString%28%29):

> The string representation consists of a list of key-value mappings in
>   the order returned by the map's entrySet view's iterator, enclosed in
>   braces ("{}"). Adjacent mappings are separated by the characters ", "
>   (comma and space). Each key-value mapping is rendered as the key
>   followed by an equals sign ("=") followed by the associated value.

That means the map is empty, you can test by calling `isEmpty()`. If it were null, it would simply print out `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You mean, like this?

```
if (nameOfanHashMap == null) {
    System.out.println("I'm sorry, this map is null!");
} else if (nameOfanHashMap.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("I'm sorry, this map is empty!");
} else {
    System.out.println(nameOfanHashMap);
}
```

Notice that a `Map` that gets printed as `{}` is *empty*, but non-`null`. A `null` map will get printed as `null`.

Answer (score 0):

If a map is `null` it is printed as `null` just like any other object.

If it is any but `null` it must be something, and `{ }` means it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an Object to System.out.println, its method toString is called.

Now, if the map has been instantiated but it is empty, the

```
toString()
```

method returns

> {}

otherwise if it is null, the toString returns

> null

Finally, the check can be done with:

```
if (nameOfanHashMap == null) {
    System.out.println("I'm sorry, this map is null!");
} else if (nameOfanHashMap.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("I'm sorry, this map is empty!");
} else {
    System.out.println(nameOfanHashMap);
}
```